# Find a sub-signal within another signal

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

Assume we have a signal, for instance:

```
x = [1 2 9 16 18 19 18 16 9 7 4 2 1 1 0 0];
```

and we want to find the location of the signal:

```
y = [10 8 4 3 1];
```

which is near to `[9 7 4 2 1]` and in this example is `n = 9`.

How can you go about finding `n`?

Comment: You can find n by looking for it.  You'll get much better responses here on SO if you show some evidence that you've at least started to tackle your own problem rather than trying to sweet-talk us into writing it for you.  And, as far as your question goes, you've got a lot to learn about sweet-talking the SO community.

Comment: I took just an example. actually in my real work, signal y is just similar to part of signal x. (it is not exactly one part of signal x)

Comment: @GarryMc You mean a one liner? Have you not even tried to implement this using a loop ?

Comment: @mathematician1975, real signal is x(1x3000) and I have signal y(1x50) which is similar to one part of signal x. I need a cost or likelihood function that input x and y and output n

Comment: @GarryMc You changed your question, from finding the _exact_ signal to finding an _approximate_ signal. That's a whole different problem!

Comment: @EitanT, yes actually. do you think it is possible to use xcorr or something like that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, you need to use some sort of cost or likelihood function. Here's a for loop to start, I'll let you find the cost function yourself:

```
x = [1 2 9 16 18 19 18 16 9 7 4 2 1 1 0 0];
y = [10 7 4 3 1];

cor = 9999;
n=0;
for i=1:(length(x)-length(y))

    % Complete this line to check if x matches y at this point
    score = SomeFunctionChecking( x(i : (i+length(y)-1) ),  y ));

    if (score < cor)
        cor = score;
        n = i;
    end
end

display(n);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Complete this line to check if x matches y at this point"? you meant I specify "score" with a number?

Comment: That's where you need to check the correlation between y and x at that point.

Answer (score 5):

**Answer to the original question:**
To find the *exact* sub-vector, you can use [`findstr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findstr.html):

```
n = findstr(y, x)
```

**Answer to the revised question:**
To find the *closest* matching sub-signal, you can use [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html):

```
M = conv2(A(:), flipud(B(:)), 'valid');
NA = conv2(A(:) .^ 2, ones(size(B(:))), 'valid');
NB = round(norm(B(:)) ^ 2);
D1 = abs(NA - NB);
D2 = abs(M .^ 2 - NA * NB);
idx = find(D1 == min(D1));
n = idx(find(D2(idx) == min(D2(idx)), 1))
```

This relies on an empirical metric that takes both amplitude and energy correlation into consideration.
It works pretty accurately in most cases. In this example it correctly yields:

```
n =

    9
```

Comment: Now, Please redefine y = [17 18 19 18 16]; so the result should be n=4; however after evaluating your code, n=10.

Comment: @GarryMc Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have corrected my answer.